# Prove that lub(S) = -glb(-S)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Using directly the definition of glb and lub, prove that lub(S) = -glb(-S), with all the standard assumptions. (Also, -S is just S with all elements *-1)

I always start with: let a = lub(S), so a>=x, and if b>=x, then a<=b (for all x in S). But I never make any progress, usually ending up with strange redundant statements, like a<=-b and b<=a etc. that don't help with the proof.

Please Help!!

Also, is a similar method used to prove glb(S U T) = min{glb(S), glb(T)} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For all $y, z \in \Bbb R$, $y \le z$ if and only if $-z \le -y$.